# Send mail to author of content

Tags: forms

I use **Drupal 9.1.4**., core **Contact module**, **Contact email** module and **Contact storage** module.

How to use the author as a referenced entity to send email to author of content (in this case autor of article) when submiting simple Contact module form?

Thanks,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Users already have a personal contact form if you [enable the contact form for users](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/contact/overview#s-configure-the-user-contact-form).

This way, you can place the link to the user's personal contact form, and then the email will automatically be sent to the author.